# Variance of sum of deviations

Tags: probability, statistics, variance, upper-lower-bounds, means

Suppose I have an i.i.d. sample $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^M$ for some positive integer $M$, and suppose that $X_i \sim X$ for some random variable $X$ with finite variance. Then, denote by
$$
E_M = \frac1M\sum_{i=1}^MX_i
$$
the empirical mean. The variance of $E_M$ (with respect to the sample) is by independence
$$
\mathrm{Var}(E_M)=\mathrm{Var}\left(\frac1M\sum_{i=1}^MX_i\right) = \frac1{M^2}\sum_{i=1}^M\mathrm{Var}\left(X_i\right) = \frac1M \mathrm{Var}(X). 
$$
All clear and standard. Now consider one point (e.g. $X_1$) and the quantity $E_M - X_1$:
$$
E_M - X_1 = \frac1M\sum_{i=1}^MX_i - X_1 = \frac1M\sum_{i=1}^M (X_i - X_1).
$$
What about its variance? The increments $X_i - X_1$ are now not independent. Can I still show that
$$
\mathrm{Var}(E_M-X_1)\leq \frac{C}M \mathrm{Var}(X),
$$
for a constant $C$ independent of $M$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
V(E_M-X_1) &= V\left(\frac{1}{M}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i - X_1 \right) \\
&= V\left(-\frac{M-1}{M}X_1+\frac{1}{M}\sum_{i=2}^nX_i  \right) \\
&= \left(\frac{M-1}{M} \right)^2V(X_1)+ \frac{1}{M^2}\sum_{i=2}^nV\left(X  \right) \\
&= \left(\left(\frac{M-1}{M} \right)^2 + \frac{M-1}{M^2} \right)V(X) \\
&= \frac{M-1}{M} V(X) \\
\end{align}

You can then deduce easily $C = M-1$ but this $C$ depends on $M$. If $M$ is bounded as $M<b$, for example, then
$$C = b-1$$